# How to style a mat-checkbox properly

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am attempting to style a mat-checkbox (material2) according to the following requirements:

A black, always visible border (regardless of checked status) (#0000000)

When checked, the "tick" will be white(#ffffff), on a coloured(teal) background (border still visible)

When unchecked, the background(inside the border) of the checkbox should be off-white (#dddddd).

So far, I have been able to set the border color, but when checked, it disappears, behind the teal color

I can set the unchecked background color, but again, the black border disappears when I do this. If I remove this setting, the border appears, but the background color is wrong.

The scss properties I am setting are as follows:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: mat-color($darkPrimary, darker); //black
  }

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: mat-color($darkPrimary, 200); //off-white
}
```

It seems that whatever I set the background as, overwrites the border style. Additionally, when I change the state of the checkbox, the black border briefly appears, then disappears again. How do I fulfil these requirements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I realised that angular check-boxes are drawn in layers, with the "tick" layer drawn last, over the top of the black border.

```
// Background border
.mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #dddddd
}

.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

By reducing the front layers' size, and shifting it a little, the border remains visible.

Answer (score 4):

To style the non checked box:

```
.mat-checkbox-background{
    background-color: transparent;
    svg path{
        fill: transparent;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
         stroke:transparent;
         //stroke is the checked mark only
        }
}
```

To style the checked box:

```
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #2cc3f8 !important;
    svg path {
        fill: #2cc3f8 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your style.css file, I have kept bg color red but you can change accordingly:

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #d71e2b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **::ng-deep** like below example.

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox.yourcheckbox .mat-checkbox-frame{
   border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That removes the border. That is the opposite of what I need.

Comment: ok than use like below example

/** No CSS for this example */
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: violet;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: darkcyan !important;
}

Comment: It did allow me to set a background colour and border, though not the problem of the border disappearing when the box is checked.

Answer (score 1):

i might be late but try using this =, make some changes according to you

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background,
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
background-color: #437891 !important;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: #fa3131;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #fa3131 !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox {
  margin-right: 8px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To style the checked box, this worked for me:

```
mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox-checked label > span.mat-checkbox-inner-container > span.mat-checkbox-background > svg.mat-checkbox-checkmark {
    /* MY STYLES HERE */
}
```

I placed it at the bottom of the global styles.css and decorated the various styles with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

To have a blue tick on a white background when checked and a white border when not checked, the following worked for me (knowing ng-deep is deprecated):

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
        border-color: white !important;
      }

  .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: white !important;

    svg path {
      stroke: blue !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 13 with Material 13-

```
<mat-checkbox color="accent" [(ngModel)]="node. Checked" (change)="checkIndeterminate(node, $event)">
        {{node.name}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

Added this to my styles.css:

```
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-frame { border-color: black !important }
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path { stroke: black !important }
```

Result: white checkbox with black border when unchecked, white checkbox with black border and black checkmark when checked.