# the color of the cross in the angular mat-checkbok

Tags: angular-material, angular11

I am using angular material checkbox
but the cross of the selected elements is white so it doesn't appear
Is there any way (css) to change its color
thank you in advance

code :

```
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="selectedUsers">
                            <div (click)="optionClicked($event, user)">
                                <mat-checkbox [checked]="user.selected" (change)="toggleSelection(user)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                                    {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.familyName }}
                                </mat-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this perhaps answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62917598/2358409

Comment: it resolved a part of the problem but i couldn't style the checkmark it is alawys white 
thank you very much