# How can I properly style a mat-checkbox in Angular with Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How do I style a mat-checkbox? Every solution I saw until now did not work for me

I tried turning view encapsulation off and using the classes like: mdc-checkbox__background but those did not do anything
I tried using the same classes in my global css sheet: also nothing.

this questions solution also does not work for me:[How to style a mat-checkbox properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984326/how-to-style-a-mat-checkbox-properly)

I am using angular 15.2.9

Clarification:
I want to know how to style the mat-checkbox/mat elements in general

Comment: which angular version are you using?and which part do you want to style?

Comment: Please edit your question and create an Angular [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) snippet. Also, clarify what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:root {
  --mdc-checkbox-unselected-icon-color:orange;
  --mdc-checkbox-selected-icon-color: orange;
  --mdc-checkbox-selected-hover-icon-color: red;
  --mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-icon-color: red;


}
```

This is what worked for me